# Cannot import an asset Library

Tags: import, asset, library

What am I doing wrong? I've tried saving the asset file in different locations (desktop, onedirve), using the user library, creating a new library but cannot get my assets to show up.
[image]

Comment: Did you mark your objects as assets?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a search query in the search field in the top right https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyRlT.png

Answer (score 0):

The Cats.txt wasn't showing up in the folder when I downloaded it from the instructor's dropbox. I opened a new blender file, opened his .blend file with all the assets, catorogorized and resaved all the assets and it worked.